# Serialize translateble entity

Tags: symfony, serialization, entity, translation

For translate my entity product use next code

```
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;
class Product
{
    /**
     * @Groups({"prod_translate"})
     */
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Groups({"prod"})
     */
    private $id;
...
```

Translatable create new entity ProductTranslation with table in DB product_translation with id, translatable_id, locale and translatble properties.
Translation work perfectly. In page just write {{ product.translation.en/sp.name }}
When use ajax pagenation use serializer for return data. 
Tried JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder and Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer

```
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory;
    use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
$products = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->findNextPageByBrandCategoryIds( array($cat), $brand, $offset, $limit );

    $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
            $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);
            $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
                return $object->getID();
            });
            $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer));
            $jsonObject = $serializer->normalize($products, 'json', array('groups' => array('prod', 'prod_translate')) );
```

Without groups serializet return "Maximum execution time 180second".
With groups return only Product data without translations.

What annotation or else manipulation must do for fix this issue? Please help!

**Edit:**
Tried Use next queries:

```
public function findNextPageByBrandCategoryIds(array $cat_ids, $brand_id, $offset=0, $limit=8 )
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

        if( !empty($cat_ids) ){
            $cat_ids = implode(',', $cat_ids);
            $qb->join('p.categories', 'c')
           ->where($qb->expr()->in('c.id', $cat_ids ) );
        }
        if( !empty($brand_id) ){
            $qb->andWhere('p.brand = :brand')
            ->setParameter('brand', $brand_id);
        }
        if( $offset>0 ){
            $qb->setFirstResult( $offset );
        }
        $qb->setMaxResults( $limit );
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

private function findNextPageByBrandCategoryIds($cat_id, $brand_id, $offset=0, $limit=8 )
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $sql = "SELECT p.id, t.id AS translate_id " .
               "FROM product p INNER JOIN product_translation t ON t.translatable_id = p.id";

        $where .= ' WHERE 1=1 ' ;
        $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);

        if( !empty($cat_id) ){
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN products_categories c ON c.product_id = p.id ";
            $where .= " AND c.category_id = ".$cat_id;
        }
        if( !empty($brand_id) ){
            $where .= " AND p.brand = ".$brand_id;
        }
        $limit = ' LIMIT '.$limit;

        if( $offset>0 ){
            $limit .= ' OFFSET '.$offset;
        }
        $sql = $sql.$where.$limit;

        $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('AppBundle\Entity\Product', 'p');
        $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('AppBundle\Entity\ProductTranslation', 't', 'p', 'product', array('id' => 'translatable_id'));
        $query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
        return $query->getResult();
    }
```

Debug almost every line - they are right.

If use setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true) - work but return products only, without translations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nik fix this issue:
On Brand, Category and Product Entities

```
    use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\MaxDepth;
    /**
     * @MaxDepth(1)
    */
    private $products;
   /**
     * @MaxDepth(1)
      */
     private $categories;

     /**
    * @MaxDepth(1)
      */
     private $brand;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Maximum execution time 180 second` message is an error that has nothing to do with annotations or the serializer.

In your php.ini you have a `max_execution_time` option to configure the limit of a script in seconds. You can also set it with the function `set_time_limit($seconds)`by code, but I would not recommend to use it.

Anyway, I would bet that you are doing a very large query. How many results are you limiting?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I use limit 8. - it's not mutch!((

Comment: If the answer solves your problem you can mark it as correct clicking in the green check. If set the limit to `0` on my development environment.

Comment: Probably, the problem is the performance of your machine. A simpler query returning less data will work for you. Try to execute the same code in another machine. Besides that, you should clarify your question, as right now the `max_execution_time` answers your question.

Comment: I work in localhost and from git to work-server and on localhost of my colleague (Nik) - same error. We have so many relations in DB.